# Storing slice of bytes in Cassandra using gocql driver

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql, nosql

How to store slice of bytes as cassandra blob type using gocql driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unspecific and you do not show us what you have done so far.

Since I don't know where your actual problem lies I will just post my `WriteRecord` function I wrote a while back when testing cassandra with the gocql package:

```
func (cs *cassandra) WriteRecord(table string, fields []string, values ...interface{}) error {
    var placeholder []string

    for range fields {
        placeholder = append(placeholder, "?")
    }
    querystring := fmt.Sprintf(insertstring, table, strings.Join(fields, ", "), strings.Join(placeholder, ", "))
    return cassandraSession.Query(querystring, values...).Exec()
}
```

As you can see the values are of type `interface{}`. So they can be anything including of type `[]byte`. Note that the following condition must be met: `len(fields) = len(values)`

I hope this helps you on your journey of becoming a `golang` expert :)